# No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "*****"with a private key was found

Tags: ios, xcode

i have created a new Provisioning development certificate but it didn't accept by xcode with error says No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "*****"with a private key was found. how to resolve this error

Comment: Attach your Keychain development certificate picture in question. follow this link to create certificate-- > https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Comment: you have to create developer certificate that matches your Provisioning profile

Answer (score 48):

Sometimes even when you have valid certificate Xcode throws this error. This is because of your account is logged off somehow.

To login back: Xcode > Preferences > Accounts then click on login and Always allow.

Comment: Worked for me! Had to restart Xcode and VSCode too in my case for it to take effect - Flutter App.

Comment: Worked, thanks! This is just one more of those many charming little gotchas than guarantee that most people will never have the patience to be software developers.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps the answer is late, but I hope to help someone in the future. You need to add the generated certificate to the keychain on your computer. And the problem will disappear

Answer (score 5):

Login to Apple Developer portal and download the certificate. Double click to install.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my developer password changed, so it gave me the error. I updated my passcode in xcode, but still gave the error. Had to completely shut down xcode and restart to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

For me running project on real device + Always Allow on appeared popup fixed issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (for react-native + expo) when running the command `npx expo run:ios -d 'My iPhone'`. For similar cases, may help:

1. open /YourProject/ios/YourProject.xcworkspace via XCode
2. run build `cmd+b` or via top menu `Product -> Build`

Answer (score 0):

**All I had to do was to**

[image] Quit my Xcode and then re-run again for changes to take effect

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.

for me, what i did is

go to Targets -> Build Settings ->
(under) Signing -> Code Signing identity
(select the certificate from the list)