# Why is Xcode giving me "no account for team id"

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

When I build my project I am getting the following errors. This is a React Native project.

[image]

All of my configurations in Signing seem to be correct:

***Main:***

[image]

***Test:***

[image]

***What I have done:***

I have searched Google and read whatever I can find. I found the following thread and checked to see if it was the problem to no avail.

https://github.com/WorldDownTown/TapticEngine/issues/3

[image]

I also tried to do a project search for the id in the error and cannot find it.

Comment: Do you have a paid developer account?

Comment: I believe so. I have Auto-Renew-Membership set to enabled and a valid credit card.

Comment: Also I did change the Apple ID at one point and reset the id to the current new id. So the id shown in the error is an old Id. I cannot seem to find the reference anywhere in the project.

Comment: Your first image tells you everything you need to know. `No “iOS Development” signing certificate matching team ID “*****” with a private key was found` some fo the solutions here may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541459/no-ios-development-signing-certificate-matching-team-id-with-a-private

Comment: I am also not sure what "Repair target SplashScreen" means. I did add the library for SplashScreen but it seems to be working fine.